# Debug dialog window turning black and unresponsive on Linux

Tags: linux, xorg, debug

Whenever I try to exit [SimVision](https://www.cadence.com/content/cadence-www/global/en_US/home/tools/system-design-and-verification/debug-analysis/simvision-debug.html) (waveform viewer utility, part of Cadence), a dialog window pops up to ask the user to confirm he/she wants to exit the application.

At times, the dialog window turns unresponsive and its content becomes black:

[image: screenshot].

I am running Scientific Linux (x86_64). I expect this is not necessarily the application's fault, but something going wrong on the local machine. What are effective ways to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X works by sending a so-called *Expose Event* to applications when they need to redraw, optionally first clearing the background (making it black).

So if an application is staying black, and the application is not responding, the *most* obvious thing to check for is something in the application. It's possible that the application is waiting on something else to happen, and isn't sufficiently threaded to stay responsive while it is waiting.

The first thing to do is a `ps` and look at the state of the application, and it's subprocessses/threads. The second thing is to get the source if possible, attach a debugger like `gdb` and figure out where it hangs, and why.

It's *very* unlikely that "something is going wrong on the local machine". Your local machine may be configured differently than the application expects, and that may cause the hang, but that's about the extent of it.